# Flutter save sqlite database data in IOS app after changing db structure

Tags: sqlite, flutter

We have flutter app with sqlite database. The issue is when we make changes to db structure like adding new column to table, flutter removes previous database with old data and creates new empty database with new changes. Is there is a way to save data from previous db version on iOS app version and add new changes to database structure without losing old data stored?

Comment: You can upgrade your database structure by adding a version number and checking it.
This might help: [Migrating a mobile database in flutter SQLite](https://efthymis.com/migrating-a-mobile-database-in-flutter-sqlite)

Comment: Page not found on this link.

Comment: Hm, ok. works fine for me. Here is another: [Migrating a mobile database in flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/migrating-a-mobile-database-in-flutter-sqlite-44ac618e4897)